# creating an highlight image map

Tags: mapping

I am working on a project in which i have a database created using mysql and php. I want to advance it by connecting an image to it. every object in my database is going to be linked to a certain part of the image that will be highlighted. 
I am not really sure how to do this. 
As of right now, i have a search feature on my database that gives me the result. 
I am willing to try any programming language that would make this easier. 
My database has about maybe 1000 entries. They are all numbers that correspond to a certain location on my image. 
My image is basically a map.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to plot a graph you can use the HTML 5 `canvas` as some JavaScript. Or better yet, use tool that already exists like [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery.html). Maybe a scatter plot is what you're looking for?